# How to scroll the screen (how to move screen)

Tags: android, xml, scroll, screen

I want to scroll main.xml screen. As I know, ScrollView is suitable for this but I used AbsoluteLayout. so it didn't work.

is there any way to do this. here is the xml codes:

```
    <AbsoluteLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ad"
    android:layout_x="0dip"
    android:layout_y="20dip"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    >
    </TextView>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editad"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="45px"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_x="80dip"
    android:layout_y="5dip"
    >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtsoyad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Soyad"
    android:layout_x="0dip"
    android:layout_y="75dip"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    >
    </TextView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a ScrollView outside of your layout like this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Your AbsoluteLayout goes here -->

</ScrollView>
```

Please note that the AbsoluteLayout class is deprecated. You should probably use e.g. a FrameLayout instead.

BR,
Christoffer

Comment: I found the solution,


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_x="1dip" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_y="2dip">
  ...

Comment: Dapina plz post it as a answer to your own question and plz summarize it a bit.Need it very badly.

Comment: @XeeMezAsHu: It's basically the same solution as in my answer. You don't actually need the outer layout. Just create a ScrollView and put a layout inside it with all the stuff you need. Please let me know if I can improve my answer in any way to help you.